# Silicone turner and grill?

Tags: grilling, utensils

I was grilling today and due to lack of equipment, needed to use a silicone turner to remove cooked burgers from the grill, after the gas was off.

Seeing as I may have exceeded the maximum temperature range rating, I checked for obvious damage to the turner (i.e., melting) of which there is none.

Is there any other damage inspection I should give the silicone turner, or is it safe to use? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the utensil is not visibly damaged in any way, it's fine.

Even if it were visibly damaged, there's no known toxicities associated with overheated silicone, so you'd still be safe; it would just be less useful.